# Termux trying youtube-dl with aria2

Tags: termux

I'm newbie and experimenting,like the title said i wanted to use youtube-dl with aria2

So this is my youtube-dl config

```
--cache-dir /sdcard/Download 

--all-subs

--external-downloader "aria2c"

--external-downloader-args "--dir=/sdcard/Download --split=16 --max-connection-per-server=16 --min-split-size=1M --continue=true"

--merge-output-format "mkv"

--embed-subs

-f "bestvideo[width=1280][fps>=30][vcodec=vp9]+bestaudio[acodec=opus]/bestvideo[width=1280][fps>=30]+bestaudio"
```

The thing is when i try to download https://youtu.be/kUd9act5EP4 (pewd's new video) around 141mb(avc1 with opus audio) and 112mb(vp9 with opus audio) its downloaded with aria2 but when I try to download https://youtu.be/FKhtrdd6p4Q (random lengthy video) around 764mb(avc1 with aac audio)its downloaded without aria2(idk what its downloaded with(native termux downloader?)).

So what is my error in this?(I have  attached a screenshot)

Oh and one more thing,how to change youtube-dl download location?[image][image]

Comment: Are you sure this is a purely Android-related question? As Termux emulates a Linux environment, this issue should be fully reproducible in a Linux machine, therefore Android-independent.

Comment: If you ask sure or no,then nope,I don't have linux machine in the first place,hence this is termux problem on android...I think,I mean I just try this in my android phone.I'm new to this,and just read the manual and my config should work based on my reading.

Comment: But yeah if its like you said then where should I ask this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah after more reading it seems that aria2  does not support segmented DASH.